# Save a Selenium exception ( with error message ) in a string

Tags: java, selenium, exception, testng

I looking for a solution to save a Selenium exception ( for example the NoSuchElement or whatever ) in a String variable.

I'm trying to do this because I want, at the end ( AfterMethod ) of my Java test class, to send a mail in case the test fail, and if it's possible, send the exception and the error message.

Doing this, I can anticipate the Reports publication ( because my test suite are very consequent and long to end )

any ideas? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a [Webdriver Listener](http://www.seleniummonster.com/eventfiringwebdriver-and-event-listeners-in-selenium/) then using the `public void onException` write the exception to the log. Let me know if you need a working example.

Comment: Ok thanks for your reply ! I never have used it, this Listener will catch all exception ? And then i send mail ? For email sending i've create an other class and i'm passing class name and ( in ideal way ) the error msg generate by the exception

Comment: @MxfrdA yeah, within the OnException(), call the method you've createdf to send email and pass in the exception variable.

Comment: Okay! I'll try this and come back to you in a moment. Thanks :)

Comment: I've tried something. If i have understand, this onException class will check every escpetion ? So i create a class and call it in my java test ?

Comment: @MxfrdA, If you followed the steps in the link therefore you have a class called WebDriverListener (or something of that sort) with a method in there called `public public void onException(Throwable arg0, WebDriver arg1)` and you will have assigned that class to your webdriver.

Then within that `OnException` method call your sendmail method and pass in `arg0` and within your sendmail method do something with arg0.